# Remainder when the dividend is less than the divisor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I am Sorry it's a silly question but its been bothering me, So I needed to ask...
In the process of division, when there is a condition like- 4/5
when the divisor is greater then the dividend.
why is the Remainder 4 ? as when the divisor is greater then the dividend then the division goes in decimals, and the final remainder comes out to be 0, then why do we do like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNfWX.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Usually we speak of remainder in the context of integers, not fractions nor decimals

Comment: When we divide $4$ by $%$ in the integers we get a quotient $0$ and remainder $4$; when we divide in the rationals/reals $5$ divides into $4$ exactly and leaves remainder $0$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner , as I have shown in the photo, when 4/5 then as we do the process of division the final remainder comes out to be 0,you are saying we speak of remainder in the context of integers. in this case if 0 is not the remainder then what is it, as we are doing division then 0 should be the remainder. right ?

Comment: "*We speak of remainder in the context of integers.*"  Precisely.  We do not talk about remainders in the context of rational numbers.  "*Why is the remainder taken to be 4* **when we can continue our process of division**"  But, you can't if we were limiting ourselves to only talking about integers.

Comment: @JMoravitz , ok I understood what you are saying, but in this case as we are continuing the process of division past 4 then if 0 is not the remainder then what is it ?

Comment: "*then what is it?*"  It is something which doesn't need to make sense in that particular context and shouldn't have been mentioned or brought up at all.

Comment: " "Why is the remainder taken to be 4 when we can continue our process of division""  What do you mean?  We CAN'T Continue or process of division any further.  For every integer $n$ and natural divisors $d$ there is a unique integer quotient $q$ where $qd \le n < (q+1)d$ and a unique integer remainder $r: 0 \le r < d$ where $n = qd + r$.  If $n=4$ and $d=5$ then the only solution for $q,r$ is that $q = 0$ (because $0\cdot 5 \le 4 < 5$) and $r = 4$ because $4=n=qd+r = 0\cdot 5 + 4$.  "then if 0 is not the remainder then what is it"  It's the quotient, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about **integers** $n$ and $d$ with $d$ positive, it is a well known theorem that we can *uniquely* find **integers** $q$ and $r$ with $0\leq r<d$ such that:

$$n = qd + r$$

We call the **integer** $q$ the **quotient** and the **integer** $r$ the **remainder**.

This is a precursor to what we eventually define as "division" and the variable $d$ is the "*divisor*" in this context.  Since you should already be familiar with division, yes this is what we would *eventually* associate with the operation $\dfrac{n}{d}$ and you will see that when $n=qd+r$ that by dividing both sides by $d$ we have $\dfrac{n}{d} = q + \dfrac{r}{d}$.

To emphasize... all this talk about quotient and remainder however, and specifically calling something "*a remainder*" is specifically in reference to when all of these... $n,d,q,r$ are integers.

> Eventually, you will learn you can extend this to talk about any commutative ring in general, commonly also talking about polynomials and elements of $\Bbb R[x]$ or similar.

Notably, we do *not* talk about "remainders" when we allow $q$ to be any real or rational number... because it makes the whole concept incredibly boring.  If you were to allow $q$ to be any real or rational, then $r$ would always be zero.  Why bother defining and talking about a concept when every case possible will always result in the same boring outcome of $r=0$?  There would be no point in ever mentioning remainders ever again.

So, the question of the quotient and remainder when talking about $5$ being a divisor of $4$ is very specifically done talking about the integer $q=0$ and the integer $r=4$... not with the rational number $q=\frac{4}{5}$ (*which isn't an integer despite that it should only ever have been allowed to be an integer*) and the (*obviously always zero*) number $r=0$

Comment: at least your $d$ should be a **positive** integer for your well known theorem to be true

Comment: ok, now I have understood the concept. Thanks for helping me JMoravitz .

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment on JonathanZ' answers with several requestions by the OP)

@Shashwat Pratap Singh
What do you think the remainder of the division $9/5$ should be? If you say $4$, then why don't you continue the calculation like you did for $4/5$ and say the reminder is $0$?

Ultimately the key part of JonathanZ' answer is **when you use the term "remainder" you imply/ require that you are staying within the integers**. If you work with rationals (as you do when the result is $0.8$), the concept of remainder makes no mathematical sense.

I think what happens is that you take a numerical routine (how to do divsion in the decimals) and declare one element of the last step as the remainder. But as JonathanZ pointed out, that routine may never end. So your concept of a remainder seems to be either is doesn't exist (if the numerical routine never ends) or is always $0$ (if it ends). In essence that is the disctinction between rational numbers that have an infinite or finite representation in decimals.

That is certainly a distinction that can be important, but is not what the concept of a remainder is about.

Comment: Heh, I think I tried to put some of the same ideas in my last two comments. Please feel free to "re-mix" whatever elements in my answer+comments you find useful. 

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing 92 by 7. The long division process goes on forever in this case. How do you know when to stop, and which value to call the final remainder?

And the answer is that when you use the term "remainder" you imply/ require that you are staying within the integers, i.e. you do not go past the decimal point.

So 92 divided by 7 is 13 remainder 1, and 4 divided by 5 is 0 remainder 4. Yes, you can say 4/5 is 0.8, but then you *would not use* the term "remainder". If you wanted to emphasize that the long division stops, you could say "4/5 is *exactly* 0.8".

Comment: As I have shown in the photo, when 4/5 then as we do the process of division the final remainder comes out to be 0,in this case if 0 is not the remainder then what is it, as we are doing division then 0 should be the remainder. right ? What I am saying is if remainder does not imply here then what is it,as we are doing division then 0 should be the remainder and 0.8 should be the quotient. why is this not the case.

Comment: "0 should be the reminder" is wrong. The remainder is 4, and it is, as I said, because when you are going to report your result with a remainder __you do not go past the decimal point__.

Comment: ok I understood what you are saying, but in this case as we are continuing the process of division past 4 then if 0 is not the remainder then what is it ? as we are basically doing division right!

Comment: Please reread the last two sentences of my answer.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan if  I am Annoying you, but I am still stuck here if 0 is not the remainder then what is it ? please help me

Comment: Let's try a different approach: What's the numerator in "5 + 3"?

Comment: 8 right ? here the denominator is 1

Comment: No. There is no numerator there. There is no division, no fraction, so there is no numerator. Do you understand that the term "numerator" does not apply to every math expression?

Comment: yes, in that context there is no numerator.

Comment: Okay, so in the context where you carry your division past the decimal point there is no longer "the remainder". I can see where your confusion comes from - that 0 is in the same location where you do pick up the remainder. But has been said multiple times here, we only use the term "remainder" when we're restricting ourselves to whole numbers, i.e. we don't go past the decimal point.

Comment: Think about it: if we go past the decimal point then either 1) we'll eventually get to 0, so the reminder would always be zero and the term is useless, or 2) we carry on forever (like in the case of 92/7), so how do we know at which step we chose to stop and say "__this__ is __the__ remainder"?

Comment: ok, now I have understood the concept. Thanks for helping me JonathanZ.

Comment: Cool. You might also want to read the answers from the other people. They give slightly different perspectives that could be useful.

Comment: yeah sure, I will read.

Comment: JonathanZ just one more thing, when the division process goes on and on then we can"t say anything, like in the case of 92/7 but in the case of 4/5 the end result of division process is 0. So I got that 0 is not remainder, can I say that{call it} it is the end result of our whole division process and surely it is not Remainder.

Comment: Well, I'd say that the "end result of the whole division process" is the 0.8 that you got up on top. If you want to indicate that you were able to carry out the division to the point where you got a zero on the bottom, the language I would use is "4 divided by 5 is _exactly_ 0.8" - the "exactly" indicates that you didn't have any loose bit laying around.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to indicate that only. Ok, finally I now understood the whole concept. Thankyou JonathanZ , really thanks for helping me. 